# jquery for each id that contains for input text only

Tags: jquery

I have this for each statement here:

```
$('*[id*=aaa]:visible').each(function () {
            console.log(this);
        });
```

just wondering if its possible to do for each input text that contains the id aaa ? not all ids with aaa just input text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> each input text that contains the id aaa ?

`*[id*=aaa]:visible` selects all elements (`*`) with an id that contains `aaa` (`[id*=aaa]`) which a visible.

Change the selector to

`input[type="text"][id*=aaa]:visible` which selects all input tags with the attribute `type="text"` and an id which contains `aaa` and is visible.

```
$('input[type="text"][id*=aaa]:visible').each(function () {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$(":input[id*=aaa]").each(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```